# How to make triplet set of columns and apply function to it

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with `mycols`. You can see mycols has `^SQN`, `^WES` and `^WGS` column sets. I want to make triplet set of `SQN`, `WES` and `WGS` columns (I dont want to include `(Pile:up)$` and `:AD$` columns) in the same order (you can see the extension is same for SQN,WES and WGS for every set) across `mycols`. In other word, I want to make a group of SQN, WES and WGS that have same extension. I then have a function called `myfunc`. I want to apply that function to each triple set thus formed.

```
mycols<- c("SQN:IDH2:G515T:R172M","WES:IDH2:G515T:R172M"    ,"WES:IDH2:G515T:R172M:AD:(Pile:up)", "WGS:IDH2:G515T:R172M","SQN:JAK1:A1432T:T478S",   "WES:JAK1:A1432T:T478S" ,"WES:JAK1:A1432T:T478S:AD:(pile:up)","WGS:JAK1:A1432T:T478S","SQN:JAK1:T1868C:V623A","WES:JAK1:T1868C:V623A","WES:JAK1:T1868C:V623A:AD","WES:JAK1:T1868C:V623A:AD:(Pile:up)",  "WGS:JAK1:T1868C:V623A")
```

result:

```
triplet1
"SQN:IDH2:G515T:R172M",   "WES:IDH2:G515T:R172M", "WGS:IDH2:G515T:R172M" 
triplet2
"SQN:JAK1:A1432T:T478S","WES:JAK1:A1432T:T478S","WGS:JAK1:A1432T:T478S",
triplet3
"SQN:JAK1:T1868C:V623A","WES:JAK1:T1868C:V623A","WGS:JAK1:T1868C:V623A"
```

So I can simply call my function to triplet1, triple 2, triplet3...

Comment: @akrun Please see the updated question. Thanks

Comment: I would rather prefer full extension match than !`Pile:up` and !`:AD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get a logical index of the strings that don't have 'P(p)ile:up' or 'AD' (at the end) with `grepl`.   Subset the 'mycols' with 'i1'.  Create a grouping variable using `sub` by removing the prefix part that starts with the alphabetic characters including the first `:` and then `split` the 'mycols1'.

```
i1 <- !grepl('(?i)(P)ile|AD$', mycols)
mycols1 <- mycols[i1]
split(mycols1, sub('[^:]+:', '', mycols1))
#$`IDH2:G515T:R172M`
#[1] "SQN:IDH2:G515T:R172M" "WES:IDH2:G515T:R172M" "WGS:IDH2:G515T:R172M"

#$`JAK1:A1432T:T478S`
#[1] "SQN:JAK1:A1432T:T478S" "WES:JAK1:A1432T:T478S" "WGS:JAK1:A1432T:T478S"

#$`JAK1:T1868C:V623A`
#[1] "SQN:JAK1:T1868C:V623A" "WES:JAK1:T1868C:V623A" "WGS:JAK1:T1868C:V623A"
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way we can match full extention and not by unselecting `Pile` or `:AD` columns

Comment: I also don't want to  include `:AD$` columns

Comment: @MAPK In the post, you said that `Pile:up` should not be included,

Comment: yes, both `Pile:up` and `:AD` columns should not be included.

Comment: @MAPK Updated the post, please check.

Comment: This is so helpful. Much appreciated!